# How to nest divs inside if statement

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, if-statement

I want to make something like that:

```
     @if ( some-statement )
     {
        <div class="row-link">
     }
     else
     {
        <div class="row">
     }
     <div class="new">some content</div>
     </div>
```

but the compiler keeps telling me that the if has no closing character!
What's wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<text>`

```
@if ( some-statement)
 {
    <text>
    <div class="row-link">
    </text>
 }
 else
 {
    <text>
    <div class="row">
    </text>
 }
 <div class="new">some content</div>
 </div>
```

and check out

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

**hope this helps**

Comment: You missed the using of text here, because as I know, Razor smart enough to understand the HTML tags without any tags,  you just need text to wrap your real multiple line text but not the HTML, please correct your answer

Comment: As far as i understand your comment, i am disagree with it. Do you read ScottGu´s post ?

Comment: Yes, I read it, let's see this part from it "Because I am not wrapping the (Out of Stock!) message in an HTML tag element, Razor can’t implicitly determine that the content within the @if block is the start of a content block.  We are using the @: character sequence to explicitly indicate that this line within our code block should be treated as content."

Comment: let's see this part also, "Razor’s smart detection of <tag> elements to identify the beginning of content regions is one of the reasons that the Razor approach works so well with HTML generation scenarios, and it enables you to avoid having to explicitly mark the beginning/ending of content regions in about 95% of if/else and foreach scenarios. "

Comment: Finally I tried it, it will not working without text as your answer, so I think this one of the 5% that Razor can't determine the tag as ScottGu said, and it's not our fault because they didn't mention when Razor can't do it :-)

Comment: Yup, Razor needs to be able to parse the markup (so there needs to be a start and matching end tag). <text></text> just tells it anything in there should be considered markup/text.

ZippyV's approach is better because it keeps things cleanly separated so Razor parses it correctly and you can read the code and the markup better. It also lines up with a future feature coming called conditional attributes.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not fluent in c# but why don't you use a variable to hold the classname?

```
@string classname;
@if ( some-statement ) { 
    classname = "row-link";
} else {
    classname = "row";
}
<div class="@classname">
    <div class="new">some content</div>
</div>
```

Or you could use a helper function. It keeps your html cleaner.

Comment: This is the correct approach. It keeps the logic separated from the structure of the markup. Easier to manage.  It also lines up with a new feature we have coming up in Razor v2 (Web Pages v2 and MVC v4) called conditional attributes.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@if ( some-statement )
{
   @:<div class="row-link">
}
else
{
   @:<div class="row">
}
<div class="new">some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider closing your `<div>` and remove your common end `</div>`

```
 @if ( some-statement )
 {
    <div class="row-link"></div>
 }
 else
 {
    <div class="row"></div>
 }
 <div class="new">some content</div>
```

Comment: No there is a difference in my site if I close the tags and it's not what I want! I also tried what zynaps said but it didn't work out. Thanks dknaack!